# search a string with spaces in sql with php

Tags: php, sql

I need to search a string in mysql with php. I get an error related to the spaces in the string. I an not fimilar with regex, I am not sure it that is my only choice.
example:

```
$ex="This and That";

$sql = 'SELECT
some_ID
FROM ' . atable. ' WHERE ' . strings. ' LIKE ' . $ex. ' AND visable=' . '1';
```

after executing I get an error like:

> "near 'That AND visable=1' at line x"

so its probably not picking up the first two words, any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Always** output your query with `echo $sql;` before you ask question here - in 90% you would solve your issue yourself

Comment: Where is the `mysql_real_escape_string()`? Protect yourself from SQL injection, it's a lot cheaper than having your website hacked. http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @Jasper: OP has reached his cap of `mysql_real_escape_strig()` for today

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just finished reading. In my case user select a number, and the number will phrase to a String-with-space. and it is done server sided. So im guessing I don't need mysql_real_escape_strig() ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the string.  They need to be encapsulated entirely for the query to execute properly.

Change this:

```
LIKE ' . $ex. ' AND
```

To this:

```
LIKE "' . $ex. '" AND
```

On a side note, make sure you are protecting your self against SQL injections AND make sure your query is properly escaped.